# I have to make schedule of matches between teams

Tags: java, arraylist

```
/**
 * Makes a schedule for teams, if there are an even number of them. 
 * Generate teams.size()-1 rounds, rotating the teams between each one. 
 * Team 0 should be at home in the first round, then it should alternate home and away. 
 * See the project description for some examples. 
 * You may assume that teams.size() >= 2 and teams.size() is even. 
 */
```

I tried using array list

```
int rounds = teams.size()/2;
for(int i=0; i<rounds;i++) {
    if (i<1){
        int home_team = teams.get(i);
        int away_team = teams.get(i+1);
        System.out.println("Team "+ home_team+" vs "+away_team);
    }
    else{
        fixtures.add(1);
    }
}
```

The first round is constructed as follows.

- The first team is at home to the second team: T1 vs. T2
- The third team is at home to the last team: T3 vs. T6
- The next team from the front (i.e. the fourth) is at home to the next team from the back (i.e. the fifth): T4 vs. T5
- We then rotate the teams; we move the last team up to the second position on the list.

  ```
   T1, T6, T2, T3, T4, T5
  ```

  You can see that T6 has been moved up to the position after T1. The first team on the list is never affected by rotation.

Comment: The instructions say `rounds` should be `teams.size()-1` but you set it to `teams.size()/2`.

Comment: I used that as well but nothing happened it says out of bound exception

Comment: @AbhishekAbhishek I didn't understand what is your question